# Git Web Interface with Documentation and Issue Tracking

Tags: git

I am looking for a web interface for git that includes documentation and issue tracking.  It seems like I can only find one or the other, and it seems dumb to use gitolite and trac together.  (And if it could read/parse POD documentation that would be an added bonus).

What is a good "management" solution for a git code base?

EDIT for clarification:

Honestly, I am looking to host something similar to GitHub in house.  I can't use a hosted solution due to the proprietary (and sensitive) nature of some of the code.  Using Gitolite and Trac together sounds like a dumb solution because it would require two interfaces, one for reading/downloading and one for issue tracking.

Currently, I am using SVN and users e-mail me with bugs and feature requests...  This is a less than manageable solution, and is not salable.  I had delusions of designing my own platform, but I am too inundated with actual work to start another side project.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? It sounds like you're opening a discussion, which is not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: FWIW, there's no ready solution, unless you use a hosted one, like github. Best choice for us was redmine/gitorious on the same host, they integrate quite allright. And @GregHewgill is totally right, ask a specific question :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438163/whats-the-best-web-interface-for-git-repositories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gitlab](http://gitlabhq.com/) seems promising, with user authentication for private access. Distributed under the MIT License.

Answer (score 1):

For a fee, you can host GitHub on your private network. If it needs to be a free solution, trac may be your best bet.

[Enterprise GitHub](https://enterprise.github.com/)

Answer (score 1):

[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) is an often used solution.

If you're looking for something similar to GitHub but at a lower cost than GitHub Enterprise, you might want to look at [Gitorious](http://gitorious.org/)